# How to handle image, more then 1 mb in size, in j2me

Tags: java-me

I am developing an application for uploading images from j2me mobile to server. As in j2me mobiles we are assigned only 1 mb of heap size, thus when I tried to upload image more than 1 mb , then it throw **OutOfMemory** exception. Is there any way to handle this issue in j2me mobiles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to load the whole image to memory (using a `byte[]`) before uploading it. If this is the case you should avoid doing it. You better use streams.
First get an `InputStream` for the file and an `OutputStream` for the server. Then copy all file contents from one to another using a buffer:

```
public static final void copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to)
    throws IOException
{
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = from.read(buffer);

    while (count > 0) {
        to.write(buffer, 0, count);
        count = from.read(buffer);
    }

    to.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for our reply.....I am uploading images using same manner, as you suggest above....the problem comes when I tried to create input stream of 1 MB size image... then it throws out of memory exception....any solution for this...

Comment: How are you opening the inputStream? Class.getResourceAsStream or Connector.open?

Comment: InputStream inputStream = fileConnection.openInputStream();

In this manner I am opening my inputstream.

Comment: So you are using Connector.open to get a FileConnection. Did you try openDataInputStream instead of openInputStream?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't try that one, but what is different between these two, as both occupy same amount of memory, But I will try once. And let you know about the status.